# HTML - Underscore line after a text & adjust Size on table

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I have been trying to work out getting a similar table to a picture that I have been studied from. Which looks like:

[image]

However I have been getting something similar:

This is what I have done:

[image]

However im getting issues when it comes to:

1. Underscore line under the bold text, Which I managed to only get on a small text which I wish to get in the whole line
2. Also I want to adjust the Size of the table so it gets stuck like in the first picture. I don't know if I did the correct way now but I assume iam on the correct way. Maybe someone here can help me out seeing the issue.

```
  table {
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: #ffcc99;
    }

    tr.hello {
       background-color: #000000;
       color: #ffffff;
    }

    tr.bigtext {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h5>Tabell 2</h5>

    <table style="width:100%">
     <tr class="bigtext">
        <td><u>Studenter</u></td>
        <td><u>17000</u></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Högskoleingejör</td>
        <td>2800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ekonomi</td>
        <td>1800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fristående kurser</td>
        <td>8300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hello">
        <td>Cirka 600 utländska studenter ingår i det totaala antalet studenter</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done all almost correct, except you should:

- not underline the border stuff.
- not use `<u>` tags.
- use the colspan for the full width.

And your code seems to be incomplete. Here's your updated code:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ffcc99;
}

tr.hello {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

tr.bigtext td {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h5>Tabell 2</h5>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr class="bigtext">
    <td>Studenter</td>
    <td>17000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Högskoleingejör</td>
    <td>2800</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ekonomi</td>
    <td>1800</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fristående kurser</td>
    <td>8300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hello">
    <td colspan="2">Cirka 600 utländska studenter ingår i det totaala antalet studenter</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: Oh there we go! 

I had no idea about the colspan and I just read about it, I assume you enter colspan 2 because its 2 coloums?

And sorry about not entering all the tables names aswell since I wanted to make this workout first. However, How could I make the table have a own size so it would look like so similar the first picture as possible in that casE?

Comment: @CDNthe2nd Yes, 2 for 2 columns spanning across. Just remove the `width: 100%` for the table so that it's on its own size. `:)`

Comment: Oh there we go! I also found another thing if you of course have time, The h5 Tabell 2 seems to be too far from the table, If I want it to be exact above the table, What would be the best method do solve that?

Comment: @CDNthe2nd Try removing the margins using `style="margin: 0; padding: 0;"` Tell me what happens?

Comment: I added in the CSS ( h5 { Your suggestion } - and it did not make any difference.

Comment: @CDNthe2nd Can you open jsbin.com and add your code and save it and send me the link?

Comment: Oh never might, You are actually correct! I forgot to add a " at the end which didn't show me anything, Looks like its all correct now! :) Thanks alot Praveen! I wish I could give you 1000 thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. I added the following under the `bigtext` tr class:

```
<tr class="underline">
    <td class="underline" colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
```

and I added the following CSS to fix the fonts and the underline:

```
 .underline {
   border-top: solid 1px black;
 }


tr:not(.bigtext) td:first-child{
       font-family: Papyrus, fantasy;
 }

 tr:not(.bigtext) td:not(first-child){
       font-family: Georgia;
 }

 tr.bigtext td:not(first-child){
       font-family: Georgia;
 }
```

The table width has also been adjusted. So the in-line CSS style was removed and this was added to your `table` css:

```
width: 70%;
```

[**Here is the JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/kp71ah0g/)

Comment: Seriously? Such a complicated answer? But why? Does `td:not(first-child)` really work?

Comment: It looks like alot complicated than the previous answer! Like Aaaloot difference since I just started with HTML!

Comment: I replied late sorry :) Only 2 things here, all your code have been moved to separate CSS rather than editing most of existing one. Font have been added to match the image. The CSS are there just to indicate which table rows are to be affected. This is just an alternative, nothing serious :)

Comment: Oh yeah! I still appreciate it honestly, Means alot for me aswell since now I can check this and also understand more in the future with it and use all this aswell! :) Thanks Ahs!